# Processing text of SQL script

Tags: sql, regex, text-processing

I want to develop tool which will prettify SQL scripts - make all special words and commands (SELECT, JOIN, FROM, etc.) upper/lower case; add square brackets; and couple other things (yes, ). I'm going to implement it as extension for my IDE or as external tool - I'm not decided it yet.

I was going to split a script by spaces, brackets, commas and periods - get separate words - and check each word to match to one of the keywords. If it matches - then capitalize/lowercase word depending on settings. If not - leave it as it was.

But then I thought that it may be other solutions.

I thought about using RegEx (unfortunately I don't know much about it). I suppose that it will work more efficient. And therefore using it will be more preferred.

Is RegEx the best way to achieve my goal? Or my initial approach is also appropriate?

Is there other ways?

P.S. I know that similar tools can already exist out there. And I will appreciate if you share them. But I want to implement my own tool for self-education reasons.

Comment: Parsing code is hard - if you just want something basic, regex will do it - if you want something that can cope with all of the intricacies of keywords within variables, lines terminating without semi-colons or go statements, etc, it gets much harder.  Best to look at others' solutions and learn from them; or just incorporate their tool for the complex parts and wrap your own requirements around it, depending on exactly which bits you're keen to do yourself.  https://code.google.com/p/python-sqlparse/, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32524/SQL-Parser, http://www.sqlparser.com/

Comment: Thanks John. I want to start from something simple, so I decide to just make words upper/lower case. It seems simple enough at a glance. Will see how things will go.